# How does autoview receive trading alerts from TradingView without using webhooks

Tags: tradingview-api

Autoview (https://autoview.with.pink/) is a chrome extension that somehow receives trade alerts from TradingView, it doesn't use webhooks, so I am curious to know how it works.

Hope someone can answer

Answer (score 0):

From their website:

> To remain decentralized, Autoview stores all of your API keys and
> information locally in your Google cloud storage. If you are running
> multiple Chromes, when the sync happens it can result in losing your
> cloud storage. Shutting all bots off and forcing you to add all your
> keys and stuff anew.

[Source: [https://use.autoview.with.pink/hc/en-us/articles/4421583262093-Getting-started-with-Autoview]](https://use.autoview.with.pink/hc/en-us/articles/4421583262093-Getting-started-with-Autoview)